# how to make a link on html that goes directly to your textbox like username? like on facebook

Tags: html, css

**CSS:**

```css
#Username { 
  position:absolute; 
  color:white; 
  top:33px; 
  left:616px; 
  font-size:13px; 
  font-family:tahoma; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body> 
  <div id="Email">
      <a href="#Username"> Email or Phone </a> 
  </div> 
</body>
```

---

Comment: Do you mean when the page gets loaded it should directly highlight that textbox?

Comment: yes exactly like that. i have a link above my text box and i what i want to do is when i click on that link it will go directly to that textbox and i can directly type on it.

Comment: Yes sure do let me know if any further query.

Comment: sorry but i'd miss understand your comment sir, what i want for my link is when i click it, it will go to my textbox/input and it will auto focus. but THANKS anyway because that auto focus fix another problem of my project. it now focus directly in my textbox when i load the page :) thanks again sir !

Comment: #mosh feu thanks for editing my question idk how did that happen on my format lol xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div>
  <a href="#txtbx">Click me and focus on text box</a>
<div>
  <div>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
<textarea id="txtbx" ></textarea>
```

Do you want something like this?
You need to add `id` attribute to your textbox and then reference it in your link.

Comment: DUDE YOU FIXED MY PROBLEM! :D THANKS great help! that "ID" attribute sure is helpful. i'll remember that :D thank again!

Answer (score 0):

Update: The correct answer is:

```
<input type="text" name="username" autofocus>
```

you just need to add autofocus within the input's tag.

if you mean something like fast scrolling to a specific div or form on the same html page, then here's how:

Create a **link** anchor in html:

```
<a href="#username" > Link Title </a>
```

and make sure you ad **id="username"** on your form input or division.

if you're using bootstrap, you can add class="inner-link" to your anchor link to make a nice scrolling effect.

If that's what you need, then i hope its helpful, if not, excuse me for posting it as an answer, cz i couldn't post it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. mohamad, but that is exactly on my code, what i wanted was to directly type on it, not just to navigate. sorry for my unelaborated question :D

Comment: @ShellEscobar Oh, perfect, then here's the answer i guess: you need to add autofocus on your input's tag, like this <input type="text" name="username" autofocus>

Comment: Thanks sir, that fixed my auto focus problem when reloading my page :D

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that when you load the page it should directly highlight or focus on username text box try this code given below

```html
<input type="text" name="username" autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password">
```

**`autofocus`** will help you to highlight the textbox when the page gets loaded

**Updated code**

Check this out hope this is what you are looking for? if any query here do let me know

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<br>
<a href="#username">Username</a>
<a href="#password">password</a>
```